# Google Pixel2 camera freezes when taking photo and recording video

Tags: android, video, camera, photo

Pixel2 camera freezes when taking a photo while recording video. It seems to work fine on a galaxy s9 with android 8.0 but not on the pixel2 with android 8.1. I dont have any other android 8.1 devices to test with.

mCamera.getParameters().isVideoSnapshotSupported(); is true.

I have setup the mediarecorder and started recording mMediaRecorder.start(); But when i call  mCamera.takePicture(ShutterCallback shutter, PictureCallback raw, PictureCallback postview, PictureCallback jpeg); The preview seems to just freeze. The video recording carries on as normal and the photo is taken, so just the preview freezes for unknown reason.

I can use cameraapi2 to solve the issue but i dont really want to do if(pixel2) use camera2 as a 1 off device.

Has anyone else had this issue?